# VBA: Working in different desktop UI scales causes unwanted automatic scaling

Tags: vba, forms

The two forms in the picture below were identical also in scale, before I fixed this issue on the bottom right one.

The bottom-right screen has appropriate UI scaling for my windows desktop setting of 100%, the top-left one does not and is stuck on the 125% scaling I use when working with my laptop outside the dock and monitor.

This issue has two annoying effects:

- The window is at 125% of appropriate size.

  - So at UI scaling 100% it is actually 125%, at UI scaling 125% it is actually 156%.
- New controls added will have appropriate size current UI scaling, so you end up a mix with differently scaled controls.

I encountered this issue in the past, but then I had accidentally solved it, not knowing how.

[image: Example of issue]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved simply by changing the width of the userform.
It will make quite a large jump in size so you will need to manually find the proper size again.

Dragging the userform size will not work, you must change it by changing the number.

[image]